# How do I build a function in C# that returns a delimited set of string numbers?

Tags: c#

Can anyone give me an example of how to build a function in C# that returns a delimited set of string numbers?

If anyone could help that would be amazing. Thanks.

EDIT: Now answered. Thanks T.S. for the help.
Along the lines of what I was going for with:

```
public string GetDelimited(int noOfLoops, string delimiter) 
{
    var build = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j=1;  j< noOfLoops + 1; j++)
    {
        if (j > 1) builder.Append(delimiter)
    }
    return build.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is "a d-limited set of string numbers"? Do you mean ["delimited"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited)? And if so, delimited by what? Can you give an example of the kind of output you expect the function to produce, and possibly some code you've already tried that we can work with?

Comment: if you want delimited strings then look at [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example in the purest, basic, sugar-less form

```
public string GetDelimited(int numberOfLoops, string delimiter) 
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i= 1;  i < numberOfLoops + 1; i++)
    {
        if (i > 1) builder.Append(delimiter);
        builder.Append(i.ToString());
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```